# Instagram url to retreive picts by hastag

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

I found this URL for retreiving images in Instagram according Hashtag.. with return as JSON, it works fine at 1st and then these last couple days intermittently resulting into not found, the URL inaccessible. What I'm trying to ask is, is this URL permanent by Instagram? if it is yes then may be sometimes it just down. otherwise is there other way ? thx guys.
this the URL :
https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/{tag_name}/?__a=1

Comment: Is this URL mentioned in their API documentation or did you stumble upon it elsewhere?  If it's not in their API docs, I wouldn't count on it being available all the time.  If it's not in the docs, I don't think any of us can say whether or not it's "permanent."

Comment: nope dude i found this in this stack.. becouse registering api app on instagram developer now is disabled so I can't create new client.. so frustrating... anyway thx for reply,
And Also there will be another new method on june 29 .. huft..